# A better way to write int main(){}

Tags: vim, vi

I recently started to use vim.
When I start coding, I usually start with following format.
('_' denotes the location of a cursor.)

```
int main(){ 
    _
}
```

Here is what I have done
1. type int main(){}
2. ctrl-o h (move left)
3. enter twice
4. ctrl-o k (move up)
5. tab (indent)

The problem is that, it takes so many key strokes.
I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I think you can use vim-plugins [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)

Comment: Use s snippet plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Things as simple as C&C++ `main()` are already defined in all [snippet plugins](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-snippets-plugins) and even in specialized plugins like [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) (I'm maintaining this one) or [c.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213).

You could also do it by yourself with abbreviations, but then you'll have to detect whether you're in a code or a string/comment context. You could define your own snippet plugin, but there already are many of them.